# Horizontal scrollbar not working in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a `scroll__cotainer` div like so:

```js
<div className="scroll__container">
            <div onClick={setBlackTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Black</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setBlueTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Blue</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setRedTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Red</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setYellowTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Yellow</p>
            </div>
            <div onClick={setGreenTheme} className="skin__option">
              <p>Green</p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

However, when I apply the following css to the container, the horizontal scroll bar doesn't work:

```css
.scroll__container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: sticky; */
  cursor: grab;
}
```

I get these two weird looking grey bars where the scroll bar should be:

[image: Pic of weird grey bars]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say doesn't work do you mean doesn't scroll or doesn't display?

Comment: Works in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/33Infinity/0v26wghd/1/

Comment: @Maxqueue Sorry, it doesn't scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The horizontal scroll can be achieved with even simpler CSS

```
.scroll__container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-maxwell-dxjns?file=/src/styles.css:0-59)

This uses the native horizontal scrolling when swiped on a touchscreen. It also works on a touchpad that supports horizontal scrolling.

If you want it to scroll when *clicking down on the mouse button and dragging the cursor*, there is no simple way to achieve this. You would need to implement mouse click and movement handlers using JavaScript, or use a 3rd party library like [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) that does so.

By the way, the weird grey lines in your example are an empty scrollbar - it's because you used `overflow-x: scroll;` to force a scrollbar to display although the elements were not overflowing the container.

Comment: you nailed this one on the head for me! Really appreciate the explanation.